# disabled button after submit form with model validation asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, validation

How Can I disable button after submit form with model validation in asp.net core?

code:

```
                    <form action="/AddComment" method="post" id="InsertCommentForm">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductId" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ParentId" value="" id="reply" />
                            <input asp-for="Email" id="Email" class="form-control mrg15B" placeholder="لطـفا یک ایمیل معتبر وارد کنید">
                            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>

                            <input asp-for="FullName" id="FullName" class="form-control mrg15B" placeholder="لطـفا نام خود را وارد کنید">
                            <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>

                            <textarea asp-for="Text" id="Text" class="form-control mrg15B area" cols="60" rows="5" placeholder="لطفا متن پیام را وارد کنید"></textarea>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>

                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" value="ارسال" id="InsertCommentBtn" class="btn btn-warning">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I tested several times, but if the validation model starts working and prevents the form from being posted, the Disable button remains.

Thankyou

Comment: Hi, what does this line `but if the validation model starts working and prevents the form from being posted, the Disable button remains.` mean? Do you want to make button disabled only after the validation passed? And the button should not be disabled If validation fails and prevents the form posting, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Hi @sina, update my answer below, pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `validate()` method in `jquery.validate.js`(***the js file has been referenced in _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml by default***) to validate the form. Only when the validation passed, the button would be disabled:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $("#InsertCommentForm").on("submit", function(event) {
            var validator = $("#InsertCommentForm" ).validate();
            var flag = validator.form();
            if(flag)
            {
                $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
            }

        });
    </script>
}
```